# Pagination shows more pages

Tags: php, pagination

I cant figure this out and already spent hours on it. Pagination increment pages to the number of post pages means if 2 pages shows data then 2 blank pages shows if 3 pages shown data then it will go up to 3 more pages and so on and so forth. Any help would be appreciated here. pages increment to the number of posts showing means if number of posts show on 2 pages then pagination next button show 2 more blank pages if numbers of posts shows on 3 pages then it will blank pages increment to 3 pages

php:

```
<?php
         $page = (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 0) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

        $perpage = 10;
        //$limit = ($page > 1) ? (((($page *2)+1)-3)* $perpage) - $perpage : 0;
        $limit = ((($page*2)+1)-3)*$perpage;

        $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM final1 LIMIT {$limit}, {$perpage}");
        $records = mysqli_fetch_all($query);

        $total = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total");
        $total = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total)['total'];

        $pages = ceil($total/$perpage);
        ?>

<?php 
              if($page>1){
                ?>
                <a class="page-link" href="?page=<?php $pagep = $page -1; echo $pagep; ?>" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
                <?php
              }
              ?>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item">
              <?php 
              if($page<$pages){
                ?>
                <a class="page-link" href="?page=<?php $pagen = $page +1; echo $pagen; ?>">Next</a>
                <?php
              }
              ?>
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: pages increment to the number of posts showing means if number of posts show on 2 pages then pagination next button show 2 more blank pages if numbers of posts shows on 3 pages then it will blank pages increment to 3 pages ..

Comment: this `((($page*2)+1)-3)*$perpage` doesn't result in the correct offset (you call it limit here). That's your problem.

Comment: @LinneaAnderson please put clarifications in the body of the question, not comments, which can be easily deleted.

Comment: @jdv Okay .. @ Jeff I do this for showing only even number of posts .. like (1*2)+1)-3)*10 = 0, (2*2)+1-3*10 = 20, (3*2)+1)-3)*10 = 40

Comment: this `($page-1)*$perpage` should give you correct offset.

Comment: you mean in limit .?

Comment: "only even number of posts"? the `$perpage` (=LIMIT) sets the _number_ of posts shown.

Comment: Yes, in limit: `$limit = ($page-1)*$perpage;`

Comment: I think you missunderstand/-interpret the syntax of sql LIMIT! the docs: _With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1)_

Comment: But I'm not quite sure what you wanna achieve.

Comment: Actually Thanks its working, but what i want first it shows the row from 0 to 10 and 20 to 40 like even rows only ..

Comment: also if you post this as an answer so i will accept it because its working now .

Comment: can you please tell me how to show only posts even like this .? first from 0 to 10 and then on the next page it will show from 20 to 40

Comment: next page should be from 11 to 20 not 20 to 40. What type of pagination are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation `$limit = ((($page*2)+1)-3)*$perpage;` doesn't result in what you need.

To fix this - for a normal pagination change it to

```
$limit = ($page-1)*$perpage;
```

*But* let's fix your variable names first, that makes it clearer how it works.
The Sql-Syntax for LIMIT is

> [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]

So let's rename the first var `to $offset`, the second to `$rowCount`

```
$offset = ($page-1)*$rowCount;
```

Now to your special case
*"can you please tell me how to show only posts even like this .? first from 0 to 10 and then on the next page it will show from 20 to 40"*
Then you need to also change the `$perpage` for each page:

```
// $page = 3; // set here only for testing
$rowCount = $page*10;
$offset = ($page-1)*$rowCount;
echo $offset.','.$rowCount;

// results:
// page=1 - 0,10
// page=2 - 20,20
// page=3 - 60,30


// So your SQL then will be 
"SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM final1 LIMIT {$offset}, {$rowCount}"
```

Comment: First page shows 1-10 thats normal now next page shows from 20-30.. and then another next page shows from 40-50, then 60-70 like it shows rows only starts from even numbers and neglect the odd numbers.. and Thanks it works !!

Comment: 20 is eqivalent to 0, we don't need 19. I was wrong